# How to redirect directory to another domain with Apache?

Tags: apache, redirect

I have an Apache server with two domains (via VirtualHost) on it.
The file setup is like this: `/example1/example2/`
`example1` is the root for `www.example1.com`
`example2` is the root for `www.example2.com`
I would like for `www.example1.com/example2/<whatever else>` to redirect to `www.example2.com/<whatever else>`
I have access to the main Apache configuration file. Any tips on how to do this? I'm not very familiar with configuring Apache, so any explanations would be very much appreciated.

The other questions related to this one lacked explanations, so I felt I had to post my own question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an .htaccess file to do this pretty quickly.  In `www.example1.com/example2/`, you would create this .htaccess file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    <Directory /path/to/vhost/>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteBase /example2/
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This does assume that you want the redirect to be a 301, and that the `example2` folder has `AllowOverride All` set.

This rule works using regex to capture the incoming URL, sans the `example2` bit, then appending it to the rewritten URL. The `R` in the square brackets tells Apache to use a Location header to the rewritten URL. The `=301` tells Apache to use a 301 Permanent Redirect header.

Comment: I'd rather not use .htaccess file if I don't have to, so how would I put this in the main configuration file? Also, how does this work?

Comment: Well, after doing some research, the RewriteEngine, etc should be in `<Directory "/example1/example2/">`
Also, the regex isn't valid. The `?` throws it off. As it is now, I can only get a redirect loop for example2.com

Comment: An infinite loop? Did you add this to both vhosts? Or even the example2 vhost?

Comment: Ah, either I didn't notice the `<Directory>` in the `<VirtualHost>`, or you added it after I saw it. Well, I got it all figured out because you pointed me in the right direction. Rather than put the `<Directory>` in the `<VirtualHost>`, I used `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example1.com` I'm sure putting it in the `<VirtualHost>` works just fine, though.

Comment: Yup, I added it after. ;) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 5):

If tou have `mod_alias` active, you can use the [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example1.com
    Redirect 301 /example2 http://www.example2.com
</VirtualHost>
```